# Restore Registry entry for standard software installation Path via CMD

Tags: windows, windows-10, registry

I messed up my registry by trying to edit the standard installation path for applications.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion
```

I should have only changed `ProgramFilesDir` but I also changed ProgrammfilesPath and all others. Now after rebooting Windows 10, I can not open any software anymore.
Not even regedit.exe, nothing works at all, with the error "could not find C:/xxx/software.exe" but it is actually located there.

The only solution I see is to fix it via cmd window (only this opens up) but I need the commands to restore or fix the ProgramFilesDir entry.

If anyone can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You could fix described problems with [System Restore](http://home.bt.com/tech-gadgets/computing/windows-10/how-to-fix-windows-10-problems-with-system-restore-11364008291943)

Comment: System Restore does not work, already tried it.